# storing file path in mysql throws away "\"

Tags: java, mysql, file, netbeans, insert

I am storing a file path in my database:

the

```
selecteddestinationfilepath = selectedPfile.getPath();
.
.
.
 state.execute("INSERT INTO "+tablename+" (filename,filepath) VALUES ('"+theselecteddestinationname+"','"+theselecteddestinationfilepath+"')");
```

But when it is stored into the database it throws away all the "\"

so instead of `D:\Programs\Rynmag181 -TFC`
its `D:ProgramsRynmag181 -TFC`

how can I fix that?

Comment: are the slashes escaped in your string?

Comment: While you need to fix the issue anyway, did you know that you can use forward slashes even on windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a **PreparedStatement**, with `VALUES(?, ?)` and `setParam(1, thesel...);` `setParam(2, ...)`,

This also prevents SQL injection and does several forms of escaping.